# Issues between include and source with coverage.py

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py

I have a project that is setup with the following minimal structure:

```
workspace/
  |- .venv/ # virtual environment
  |- .vscode/ # ide settings
  |- my.repo.folder/ # git repo. Note: these have periods in their names
    |- coverage/
      |- .report # data file
      |- html/ # folder for HTML report
    |- service / # service package folder
      |- __init__.py
      |- ...
    |- tests/ # tests folder
      |- test_a.py
      |- test_b.py
      |- ...
    |- conftest.py # pytest configuration
    |- pyproject.toml # project configuration
    |- handler.py # AWS Lambda entry
```

Generally, we have a workspace folder that we'd clone a single repo into. At the top level there are workspace configuration, virtual environment, etc. artifacts alongisde the repo itself. Within the repo we have a `service` folder for all source code as a python package and a `handler.py` file as the entry point (this is for an AWS Lambda Function). Additionally, we use poetry for all packaging and dependency management, so project configuration is stored within the `pyproject.toml`. I have included the configuration settings below.

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "-v"
testpaths=[
    "tests"
]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "INFO"
log_file = "logs/pytest.log"
log_file_level = "DEBUG"
markers = []

[tool.coverage.run]
source = ['service']
command_line = '-m pytest tests'
dynamic_context = "test_function"
data_file = 'coverage/.report'

[tool.coverage.report]
show_missing = true

[tool.coverage.html]
show_contexts = true
directory = 'coverage/html'
```

The issue is that when `source = ['service']`, Coverage works as expected but does not include the core `handler.py` module. When I replace that line with `include = ['*/service/**', '*/handler.py']`, nothing is captured by coverage.py. In fact, if I omit that line altogether, nothing from `service` or even the `handler.py` is included by default. The only modules that are reported on are from the `.venv` from OUTSIDE the CWD (super confusing), `conftest.py`, and the test modules within `tests`. My intuition would be that if I can specify `service` within the `source` option, then coverage should at least cover that folder within its default path as well, right?

Can someone please help me troubleshoot how to get coverage to report off of both the `handler.py` module and the `service` package?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
source = ['service', 'handler']
```

Comment: I tried this and it still only reports based on the `service` package alone. To my knowledge, `source` only accepts packages. But the weird thing, again, to me is that if I completely omit source, it doesn't even recognize `service` as a package to apply coverage over.

Comment: Add `--debug=trace` to your `coverage run` options, to see why it is excluding handler.py.